# How to handle Click event for Buttons in UserControl - Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, user-controls, windows-store-apps

In Windows Store Apps, I create a UserControl to encapsulate and reuse code-behind and layout XAML.

"ForumItem.xaml" UserControl :

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="YesButton" Content="Button" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="NoButton" Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I Create ten items form my UserControl and then add it to Grid in Code-Behind for myPage :

```
Grid grid = new Grid()
for ( int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    ForumItem sss = new ForumItem();
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
    row.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    Grid.SetRow(sss, flag);
    grid.Children.Add(sss);
}
```

I want to handle Click event for two Buttons in ten user control , I really appreciate any help. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Declare `NoClick` and `YesClick` events in the UserControl.
They respectively should execute the handlers for the Yes and No buttons.
Expose them in the UserControl, and wire them up while you populate your grid.

Comment: This work fine !! , I swear to god i tried this solution thousand time but only this time work !
Thank you bit, but to set this as a right answer , can you please answer the part two of my question : i know now how can handle YesButton Click event . How can i know which YesButton was clicked on it among the ten buttons  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Expose the in the UserControl?" How is that done?